# How to remove letters from a string of alphabets

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

```
def remove_keyword(modified_keyword):
  global plain_alpha
  for i in modified_keyword:
      if i in plain_alpha:
        plain_alpha.replace(i, "")
        print(plain_alpha)


  return plain_alpha

print(remove_keyword(keyword))
```

## -------------------------------------------------

So the request is:
 the method return the modified string.
 In this example, all the characters in “zebras” are removed from the plain alphabet
“abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz” to produce “cdfghijklmnopqtuvwxy”.

Comment: What isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String methods do not modify strings in-place as strings are immutable. That means calling `replace` does not modify `plain_alpha` in any way; a new string is returned instead. Change

```
plain_alpha.replace(i, "")
```

with

```
plain_alpha = plain_alpha.replace(i, "")
```

I focused on making the code work only. Please feel free to edit/comment improvements such as not using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the desired output.

```
>>>a='zebra'
>>>b='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> for i in a:
        b=b.replace(i,'')
>>> b
'cdfghijklmnopqtuvwxy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this and it should work

```
plain_alpha = plain_alpha.replace(i, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Checking if a letter is in the string is redundant.
2. String in python is immutable, so replace won't change the string content but will return a new string instead.

   ```
   def remove_keyword(modified_keyword):
   global plain_alpha
   for i in modified_keyword:
       plain_alpha = plain_alpha.replace(i, "")
   return plain_alpha

   print(remove_keyword(keyword))
   ```